What am I doing wrong in this array sorting?
I have this code that searches the minimum value and the maximum value in a list, adding and reducing the range of where will it search for those values, but the list ends up close to be sorted, but they aren't and I still can't figure how to fix this.
Basically this is the part where it searches for the minimum and maximum values and their positions.
a = [6, 3, 9, 7, 1, 8, 2, 4, 5]

def minimoMaximo(a):
    _min = float('inf')
    _max = float('-inf')

    pos = 0
    posMax = len(a)-1
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if (a[i] < _min):
            _min = a[i]
            pos = i
        if (a[i] > _max):
            _max = a[i]
            posMax = i

    return pos, posMax

Then it's supposed to look for the position of the minimum in the list, save its value, delete its current position and insert it to its proper position, then it looks for the position of the maximum and do the same, reducing the range where it searches the minimum and maximum values by every iteration:
medio = ((0 + len(a)-1)//2)
posi = 0
posiMax = 0
posf = len(a)-1
final = len(a)


for i in range (medio):
    poseMin = minimoMaximo(a[i:final])
    elemMin = a[poseMin[0]+posi]
    del a[poseMin[0]+posi]
    a.insert(posi, elemMin)
    posiMax = posiMax + 1  

    elemMax = a[poseMin[1]+posiMax]
    del a[poseMin[1]+posiMax]
    a.insert(posf, elemMax)

    posi = posi + 1
    posf = posf - 1
    final = final - 1


But turns out it doesn't actually sort the array, I was using pythontutor.com to see where the issue is and it seems like it begins in i = 3 of this line:
for i in range (medio):
I was trying that for it to make elemMax = 7, but it makes elemMax to be 4
Visual explanation of Pythontutor.com
It seems to be because posiMax is 3, so it moves elemMax one position forward. I tried to add +1 to posiMax after the whole process, but doing so makes 9 to be in the 3rd position:
Visual explanation of the issue with the 9 value
I've tried a lot of things, but I don't understand what is changing the list, so elemMax is one position forward?? I don't have a clue

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

often deleting items from list when you work with this list in loop can make problems. Because after deleting items change indexes but for-loop doesn't know it.

Instead of deleting and inserting, a sort typically swaps elements so that the structure of the list stays intact.

"It should make elemMax = 7, but it makes elemMax to be 4". I don't understand what the question is. The other website already gave you a clear explanation of why the result is 4. What is your reasoning for why it should be 7 instead? What specifically confuses you about the explanation?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a specific question - which will come out of your best attempt to understand and locate a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the specific part of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely expect something), and don't understand why.

Which is to say: we don't want to have to dig through and follow along with all the rest of the code; the overall task you are trying to complete is not relevant to the question you are asking. It is your responsibility to strip the code down to the essential part that works differently from how you expect; explain what result you got and what result you thought you should get instead; explain why you think you should get that other result; and ask a clear question about what it is that you don't understand.

@furas
I already tried with print debugging, that's why I changed to Pythontutor, I really don't understand why is this failing.
Also, I've made before a code to do this exact thing but only with minimum values, so I'm basically trying to modify it to add the maximum values, so the code is optimized, I'm a beginner :<

@KarlKnechtel
I see, sorry about this, I did read the How to Ask section, I just thought it wouldn't make sense if I just explain one part, considering the part that's making trouble depends on the function I made before to work.
My question is basically... since this works for sorting the array through the minimum values, how can I make it work by using the maximum values too? Or at least, what's changing in the list that it makes elemMax to be in one position ahead?
I'm sorry, I'm new to all this, I'll edit my post.

You really need to read [mre]

We can't run this code and test it ourselves because it has several undefined elements.  What is minimoMaximo()?  What is a?  We don't know.  It's your job to provide us with a COMPLETE example that we can cut and paste and run EXACTLY as-is.

@furas It's not called "debuging". It's called "debugging".

@JohnGordon Sorry, I deleted those parts of the code because I took what Karl said like that, I'll add it again. I'm new to this.

@MatBailie Yeah, the parts of the code that were before in the post were necessary for the part with the problem to work, that's why I added it in the first place :(
